# How to rotate a shape defined by two radiuses maintaining distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am not sure how to ask but I struggle with this problem for some time now.

I got an algorithm which calculates a shape by many points around its midpoint. In fact $\pi/4$ is defined by a radius, the next $\pi/4$ is defined by a seconds radius. Mirroring/Rotating gives the complete shape. It looks like some kind of ellipse. The mid of that shape is my coordinate origin. For every point defining the shape I know the tangent. The center of the two radiuses does not lay in the midpoint but on the x- and y-axis.

I now want to rotate the shape. But I want its uppermost point (speaking of y-axis) to be constant. So I have to rotate around a angle and translate the midpoint so that the current shape-defining point is at the top and no other point has a higher y-axis value at that moment.

So let us say the topmost point when starting is $P_0(0; 19.5)$. The radius for this point is at $MR_A(0; -22.75)$ ($r = 42.25$). The midpoint of the shape is the coordinate origin $(0; 0)$. The next point on the shape surface is $P_1(1.69; 19.47)$ at an angle of $2.29°$. To have it at the topmost position (kind of projecting it on $P_0$), I rotate the midpoint around $MR_A$ by $2.29°$ and get a translation point or move point of $(-0.91; -0.02)$.

This works fine until I get to $P_{15}(23.26; 12.52)$. This is the first point using the other radius with $MR_B(15; 0)$ ($r = 15.0$). Rotating the midpoint around the other radius does not seem to be the solution. Experimentally I can see it is wrong. My thoughts are missing some translation required.

How would I continue?

It is easy to say that at $90°$ the point on the shape is $(30; 0)$ and the translation/move point is $(0; -10.5)$.

Sorry I am not very sure about how to formulate the problem so do not hestitate to ask questions for unclear things...

---

Edit: I uploaded a small sketch of the shape and points: [image: Shape Sketch]

Comment: Why don't you rotate around the origin?

Comment: Or, even better, if you want the uppermost point to stay fixed, rotate around it and no translation will be needed.

Comment: @Aretino I cannot just rotate it because it should always touch and never collide with a line on $y = 19.5$. To do this the tangents on every point must be in horizontal position when the point is on $P_0$. The points for the first $\pi / 4$ which use $r_A$ are easy to do, I can rotate the midpoint around $MR_A$. But I fail with the points belonging to $MR_B$.

Comment: What does the top left $\pi/4$ in the diagram refer to? It seems to be neither an angle at $MR_A$, nor an angle at the origin? And, related to that, is there a kink in the shape where the two quarter circles with different radii meet? If not, how are you ensuring continuity of the tangents?

Comment: @joriki I think ZoolWay is drawing two circle arcs: the first centered at $MR_A$ having radius $42.25$ and the second centered at $MR_B$ having radius $15$. The two circles are tangent at $P_{15}$, so he draws the first arc from $y$ axis to $P_{15}$ and the second from $P_{15}$ to $x$ axis, clockwise. The figure is completed by adding the symmetric of this double arc with respect to the axes.

Comment: @Aretino: What does "The two circles are tangent at $P_{15}$" mean? If you mean that the two circles intersect at this point, my confusion is only increased -- then the other two occurrences of $\pi/4$ in the diagram are also not clear. Does $\pi/4$ in fact appear anywhere in this entire construction?

Comment: @joriki Forget about $\pi/4$: the actual angle is $\angle P_0 MR_A P_{15}\simeq 61.7^\circ$. But the two circles actually touch each other at $P_{15}$, as you may easily check.

Comment: I'd like to hear from the OP before I "forget about $\pi/4$"; this is, after all, the first piece of quantitative information in the question, and the only one in the first three paragraphs; it seems unlikely that it's completely false and was put there for no reason at all.

Comment: Seem I confused more mit $\pi / 4$ than it helped ;) I just wanted to have 8 parts and the angle is in relation to $M(0; 0)$ and shows where the area of each radius and there midpoints switch. @joriki

Comment: @ZoolWay: But that seems to contradict Aretino's interpretation that the switch occurs at $P_{15}$, which is not at $\pi/4$ from $(0,0)$? But that interpretation makes a lot of sense otherwise. Is it wrong, then?

Comment: @joriki: You are right, $P_{15}$ is not at $\pi/4$... that was a misinterpretation in the original algorithm by me. Will check again. But Aretino's interpretation about the switch is correct, that is what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding a quite confused exposition, I think I've understood your question. Rotating the shape around $MR_A$ is fine as long as the rotation angle $\theta$ is less than $\alpha=\angle P_0 MR_A P_{15}\simeq 33.4^\circ$. For $\theta>\alpha$, let $O'$ be the point obtained by rotating of $MR_B$ around $MR_A$ of angle $\alpha$ (this point belongs to the $y$-axis) and go on rotating your shape around $O'$ instead of $MR_A$. To be more precise, if $S$ is the initial shape and $S'$ is the same shape rotated by $\alpha$ around $MR_A$, then for $\theta>\alpha$ you must rotate $S'$ around $O'$ by $\theta-\alpha$.

Comment: That makes sense as when you come to the point where you "switch" the radius $MR_B$ already would have rotated as well... Will check this out.

Comment: Ok, the switch from $MR_A$ to $MR_B$ is done at $33.4°$ (calculated $arctan(((A / 2) - R_B) / (R_A - (B / 2)))$, $A = 60$, $B = 39$, A and B are width and height of the shape). $MR_B$ rotated around $MR_A$ by $33.4°$ makes $O'(0;4.5)$. For $\alpha = 90°$ I would now require to rotate $P_{90°}$ around $O'$ by $90° - 33.4° = 56.6°$.

Comment: You must rotate $P_{90°}$ first by $33.4°$ around $MR_A$ (the resulting point $X$ is $(12.52, 12.76)$) and then you must rotate $X$ by $56.6°$ around $O'$ to get the final point.

Comment: Following this $P_{90°}''$ at the ends up at $(0; 19.5)$ which is perfectly fine - thats the target point where it should have gone. Doing the same transformations on $M(0; 0)$ I get a result of $M''(0; -10.5)$ - which is just logically the correct value I was searching for. I will build this up to an algorithm and do this for the whole set of points. Guess you brought me back to the right way.